# How to delete data from database in Laravel 8.*

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to delete city from my db but i really got no clue what to do next.
Since I didnt find anything about deleteing data from db for Laravel 8.* I think this might be usefull for other stackoverflowers too.

My **error** says clearly that I'm missing some arguments,

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CityController::delete(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 1 expected
```

While my controller says that he expected type 'object' but only found array

```
Exoected type 'object'. Found 'array'. intelephense(1006)
@var array $todelete
```

**Here is Route from web.php**

```
Route::delete('cities', [App\Http\Controllers\CityController::class, 'delete'])->name('cities.delete');
```

And this is form I'm using to delete

```
<form class="float-right m-0" method="post" action="{{ route('cities.delete') }}">
                                @method('delete')
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="cityId" value="{{ $city->id }}">
                                    <button> <i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

**Edit**

After solving previous problems, I'm stuck on another error:

```
Call to a member function delete() on array
```

Here is how my "CityController"s function looks like after updates

```
public function delete(Request $request)
    {
        $cityId = $request->get('cityId', false);
    // TODO: Check for validation
    $todelte = DB::select('select '.$cityId.' from cities');
    $todelte -> delete();
    return redirect('frontend/city/index');
    }
```

Correct query to delete stuff:
DB::table('cities')->where('id', $cityId)-> delete();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with not getting the `$id` parameter passed has to do with your route not accepting any parameters.
Your call is `DELETE /cities`, which does have any parameters.
If you changed that to `DELETE /cities/5`, than you could get a parameter passed down the line.

In order to get the parameter to your controller you should change your route as follows:

```php
Route::delete('cities/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\CityController::class, 'delete'])->name('cities.delete');
```

This way the `{id}` part will be passed along to the function specified in the callback. To make your form work with that new route you should change the action-part of you form to direct to the new URL.
I suggest using the 2nd parameter as well so you get:

```php
route('cities.delete', ['id' => $city->id])
```

Then you can remove the hidden input.

If you do want to keep the existing form you need to use the `Request` as a parameter in your delete-function. That would look like this:

```php
public function delete(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $cityId = $request->get('cityId', false);
    // TODO: Check for validation
    $todelte = DB::select('select '.$cityId.' from cities');
    $todelte -> delete();
    return redirect('frontend/city/index');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I knew it before and I tried already with your method earlier but I finished with different type of bug:

Call to a member function delete() on array. It wasn't showed as a bug before but I had it inside controller (mentioned in second code quote)

Comment: Also, url after those chances looks kinda funny:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cities/%24id?id=29

Comment: That is because you're printing the route in `{{ }}`-tags, those performl HTML-encoding over your URL. If you change those to `{!! !!}` then is should be printed without encoding.

Comment: I was just dummie and i did 'id' instead of {id}. Now url looks legit, however i still cant do anything because of the error:
Call to a member function delete() on array.

Comment: Well that's a whole new issue, you're selecting data from the database and trying to call `->delete()` on that, but the `DB::select` most likely returns an array. You should change you query to a delete-query or use Eloquent to manage these things, but that requires some more rewriting.